# How to Describe Interaction Between Variables

Tags: correlation, statistical-significance, categorical-data, interaction, demography

Say I have two demographic variables, job$\in{j_1, j_2}$ and
lives$\_$alone$\in${YES, NO}.
I also have N books $B_1$, $\ldots$, $B_N$, each labelled with a genre that I know in
advance, out of {fiction,non-fiction}.

In an experiment, I ask representatives of each instance of job, and each
instance of lives$\_$alone, to label the books (off course, they do not know the
true labels). That is, I have 4 treatment groups: job=$j_1$ and lives$\_$alone=YES,
job=$j_1$ and lives$\_$alone=NO, job=$j_2$ and lives$\_$alone=YES, job=$j_2$ and
lives$\_$alone=NO. So, in the end, each book has 4 labels, one coming from each
treatment group.

At this point, I can compute metrics such as accuracy, precision, recall, etc.,
to get an idea about which group is best at correctly labelling the books. I
could also do statistical tests to see if the difference in e.g. accuracy
between two groups is significant.

However, where I am stuck is figuring out if there is any interaction between
the two variables, job and lives$\_$alone. How do I begin to make a statement
about how the two variables interact?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An interaction means that the effect of one variable depends on the level of the other. You can examine whether the difference between live_alone = YES and live_alone = NO differs between those with job=$j_1$ and those with job=$j_2$. If there is a difference between these differences, then you have an interaction. Of course, you need to statistically test for the presence of an interaction, which regression or ANOVA can do.